# Arduino IR code not working (USING TINKERCAD)

Tags: c++11, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

**ARDUINO PROBLEM**

[image]

**So this is the circuit bord **

THE PROBLEM: when I try to run the code and try to press any button on the IR remote it does nothing ( it doesn't print the hexacode ! )

- I have tried to change the circuit and tried to change the code. I was looking fro the arduino forums and tried every one, but still it doesn't work .
- Is there a problem with tinkercad. simulation or is it with the code ?

CODE:
`https://pastebin.com/1Uhn1j3a`

CODE:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

const int RECV_PIN = A5;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
}

void loop(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
        Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
        irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

Comment: tinkercad link: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/c0eMcRRcDgp-robot-ir-code

Comment: Pins 4 and 5 on your L293D aren't connected to GND (which they should be) according to your circuit layout. Is that just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Two of the L293D ground pins are, according to your circuit layout, connected to the +5V rail inadvertantly. And the other two are connected to GND. According to [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/why-there-is-4-ground-in-l293d) post the grounds are **all internally connected,** so in effect you would be shorting the +5V output to ground.